# Expo build for Android stuck in queue

Tags: android, react-native, build, apk, expo

I'm trying to build the expo app with `expo build:android` but it just stuck with the message `Build in progress...`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit**

You can get more informations about the "Priority" plan [here](https://expo.io/developer-services)

**Original**

Since a few days, expo has a new feature called "Priority builds".

You obviously have to pay to access this service.

"Priority builds" is not is the docs yet, and they will probably communicate about it with the upcoming SDK 36.

There's now a queue for builds and people with a paid account will have their build in top priority, without waiting. Without it, you have to wait a build server to be available.

This "issue" seems to impact only recent expo's users. With an old enought account, there's no wait time at the moment.

Comment: yea its pay to win now :D